# Uninstaller for amd catalyst /usr/share/ati/amd-uninstall.sh, does not exist or cannot be found

Tags: drivers, ati, uninstall, catalyst

I am unable to uninstall the AMD Catalyst driver using the script specified by the AMD instructions [here](http://www2.ati.com/relnotes/catalyst_11.3_linux_installer.pdf).

When I run the command:

```
sudo ./amd-driver-installer-13.35.1005-x86.x86_64.run --uninstall
```

I get the error below:

```
uninstaller for amd catalyst /usr/share/ati/amd-uninstall.sh, does not exist or cannot be found
```

How can I remove these drivers now?

Comment: How did you install the driver ? apt-get ?

Comment: No.  I installed it by running the following:

sudo ./amd-driver-installer-13.35.1005-x86.x86_64.run

which brought up a dialog and I followed the instructions.  Now because of this driver installation the desktop will not appear so I need to remove it.  But I can't because it needs to be uninstalled using the script at the path /usr/share/ati/amd-uninstall.sh but that path does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

From http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Saucy_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx

> Removing Catalyst/fglrx
>
> The uninstall script in the first command will only exist if you downloaded the drivers and installed them directly (rather than building packages as this guide does). Skip the first command if it does not exist.

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
```

> If you plan on using open-source drivers, you will need to reinstall some packages because Catalyst overwrites or diverts some key 3D libraries with proprietary versions. For more information on this issue, see this Ubuntu wiki page

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
sudo rm -f /etc/ati
```

> If you receive
>
> $ E: Internal Error, No file name for libgl1-mesa-dri
>
> Change the third command above to:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 xserver-xorg-core
```

Comment: +1 for providing up-to-date information that is relevant for Ubuntu 14.10. I had to replace your first link with the link for trusty: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Trusty_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx to get the wiki page for Ubuntu 14.04.